# Django Rosetta TypeError at /en/rosetta/files/project/

Tags: python, django

I want to add rosetta to my project.I installed version 0.9.7 (tried 0.9.5) and added to INSTALLED_APPS 'rosetta'. I have error:

> TypeError at /en/rosetta/files/project/
> expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

My urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('order/', include('order.urls', namespace='order')),
    path('social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL)
```

**Python** == 3.8.10

**Django** == 3.2.7

Comment: share the `INSTALLED_APPS ` list

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',   
    'shop',
    'cart',
    'order',
    'bootstrap5',
    'social_django',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'utils',
    'rosetta'
    
]

Comment: @ShreeyanshJain